# Create checkboxes with textboxes in google forms

Tags: checkbox, textbox, google-forms

I wanted to create google form in which there are multiple textbox options and after selecting the checkbox, I wanted to add another textbox for that corresponding checkbox.
For Example, Suppose there is a multiple choice question and if someone selects a particular option, I also want the explanation for selecting that option like:
`Select the timeslots in which you are busy?`
`Slot 1` - `___________________(Reason)`
`Slot 2` - `___________________(Reason)`
`Slot 3` - `___________________(Reason)`
I have tried to explain as best as I could.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

After a long research,I got that there is no standard way of doing it presently on google forms. But, one thing that can be done is to add every option as a question with the title as `Slot x` and add with `paragraph text` as the question type.
Also, I did not find any other third party form apps which allow this.
Hope this helps anyone else looking for the solution to this.